# Wagtail: filter available pages in PageChooserPanel

Tags: wagtail

In Wagtail, is it possible to filter pages that show up within the `PageChooserPanel` page?

For example if I'm setting a link for a french page, I would only want to see pages marked as French. Something like the fake example below:

```py
class MyPage(Page):

    french_link = models.ForeignKey(
      Page,
      null=True,
      blank=True,
      related_name='+',
      on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )

    panels = [
        # something like this that can
        # limit the pages to only ones where lang equals fr
        PageChooserPanel('french_link', filter=limit_by_lang), 
    ]


def limit_by_lang(query):
    return query.get(lang='fr')
```

Thanks.

Comment: See https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/1250 . Doesn't look like this is currently possible. There is a global hook that you can use (mentioned in the comments on the issue), but it would apply to all page choosers.

Comment: Perfect, that gives me a good starting point. Thanks a lot!